# What happens when we unmarshal empty Json into struct in golang?

Tags: json, go

I have a problem with parsing empty JSON string into a struct in Golang. In the playground, when I run this code, the marshal function returns `unexpected end of JSON input`. But is this the official return of Golang when we parsing an empty JSON string into a struct?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var respBytes = []byte{}

type ResultStruct struct {
    result []map[string]string
}

func main() {
    var jsonData ResultStruct
    err := json.Unmarshal(respBytes, &jsonData)
    fmt.Println(err)

}
```

Comment: An empty string is not valid JSON, nor is a string containing all whitespace.  If you need to handle empty or all whitespace strings, check for these conditions before calling Unmarshal.

Comment: You're asking what happens, but then you tell us what happens. What is your actual question?

Comment: I am not sure that it is the official way of Json Unmarshal in Go or just a special case.

Answer (score 1):

For this line: `var respBytes = []byte{}` You have created an empty byte slice. Which `json.Unmarshal`[doc](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) will not parse it properly. Because **Empty** is not a valid JSON string.

This is how to unmarshal an "Empty" JSON string:

```
var respBytes = []byte(`{}`)
```

[Go JSON example](https://gobyexample.com/json)

Comment: In case if the JSON is the response of a request that is 404 or 500. How about the error when parsing JSON.

Comment: If this JSON is used as the RESTful API response. You may not want to implement in this way. Oftentimes, we use a `struct` with JSON tags that offer information to Unmarshal function. And for advantage, you can control the field behavior via changing the tags. Please have a look at this [example](https://gobyexample.com/json)

Comment: Actually, I am using response from a server that I cannot control. Sometime the server returns 404 or 500. So I want to make sure that the response is empty string and Unmarshall returns a `not nil` error.

Comment: All errors codes should be handled as errors. Still if you just want to check if Unmarshal skipped un-marshaling then use pointers. The pointer will remain nil if Unmarshal did not do anything. I have posted the details

Comment: I know what you mean. In this case, you can check the response body manually for the case that body content will be **Empty**. Like 404 and 500. And then bypass the unmarshal logic.

Comment: @toantruong Then _evaluate_ said response code and do not try to unmarshal when the server explicitly says „I do not have the resource you are asking for“ or „I have an internal problem processing your request“.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ``` var respBytes = []byte(``) ``` OR `` var respBytes = []byte(`{}`) ``

Now your question if we un marshal empty json into struct then it will just skip it.

Following code just leaves jsonData ResultStruct with init values:

```
var jsonData ResultStruct
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{}`), &jsonData)
fmt.Println(err)
fmt.Println(jsonData)
```

Now just with default initializations also it would print same thing:

```
var jsonData ResultStruct   
fmt.Println(jsonData)
```

The only way to check if unmarshal was not successful(or meaningful) is to use **pointer type**. The pointers are nil by default (or on initialization). If data is properly unmarshalled in them then they will point to proper value otherwise they will remain nil. You can leverage this and use nil check on pointer like `if jsonData.Result == nil {}`.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type ResultStruct struct {
    Result *[]map[string]string `json:"result"`
}

    func main() {
        //case 1
        var jsonData1 ResultStruct        
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"result":[{"Name":"ADF","Job":"ENG"},{"Name":"ASK","Job":"TEST"}]}`), &jsonData1)
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println(jsonData1.Result)

        fmt.Println()

        //case 2
        var jsonData2 ResultStruct        
        err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{}`), &jsonData1)
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println(jsonData2.Result)

    }
```

In above, case 2, we can check if jsonData2.Result is nil. If it is nil that means Unmarshal was not successful in retrieving the results